# How to get JSON response in to PHP variables

Tags: php, json

I am getting following response in JSON format and I want it to convert it into PHP variables.

**JSON:**

```
{"CreateTransactionResponse":{"CreateTransactionResult":{"TransportKey":"aa900d54-7bfb-47e9-a5de-e423ec34a900"
,"ValidationKey":"fbb28b32-f439-4801-a434-99c70aa388ca","Messages":{}}}}
```

output should be **PHP:**

```
$transkey = aa900d54-7bfb-47e9-a5de-e423ec34a900;
$vkey = fbb28b32-f439-4801-a434-99c70aa388ca
```

please advice me how to do it.

Comment: simplest way posted, mark as answer if its what you are trying to find. So that everyone who visit in search of the answer for same question will see what worked for you best.anyway best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use json_decode();

```
 $result= json_decode($jSon);

 var_dump($result); // to see the output
```

Comment: Now if i want some specific values from dump then how we can get these values?

Answer (score 1):

json to array(`json_decode`) and then `extract` from array.

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
extract($arr);
var_dump($CreateTransactionResponse);
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
  'CreateTransactionResult' => 
    array (size=3)
      'TransportKey' => string 'aa900d54-7bfb-47e9-a5de-e423ec34a900' (length=36)
      'ValidationKey' => string 'fbb28b32-f439-4801-a434-99c70aa388ca' (length=36)
      'Messages' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

More about [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

use `$CreateTransactionResult['TransportKey']` to access Transport Key from JSON. Similarly `$CreateTransactionResult['ValidationKey']` for Validation Key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your json try to decode it first:

```
$result = json_decode($yourJSON, true);

foreach($result['CreateTransactionResponse'] as $key => $val){
   echo $transkey = 'TransportKey= ' . $val['TransportKey'] . '<br/>;
   echo $vkey = 'ValidationKey= ' . $val['ValidationKey'];
}
```

Or if it is an array of JSON's

```
$result = json_decode($yourJSON, true);

$data = [];
foreach($result['CreateTransactionResponse'] as $key => $val){
   $data[] = [
        'TransportKey' => $val['TransportKey'],
        'ValidationKey' => $val['ValidationKey']
   ];
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try this code it will work  
$JSON='{"CreateTransactionResponse":{"CreateTransactionResult":{"TransportKey":"aa900d54-7bfb-47e9-a5de-e423ec34a900" ,"ValidationKey":"fbb28b32-f439-4801-a434-99c70aa388ca","Messages":{}}}}';    

    $arr=json_decode($JSON, TRUE);
    foreach ($arr as  $value) {

    foreach ($arr['CreateTransactionResponse'] as $key => $var) {
        echo 'TransportKey = '.$var['TransportKey'].'<br>';
        echo 'ValidationKey = '.$var['ValidationKey'].'<br>';
        foreach ($var['Messages'] as $key => $msg) {


        echo 'Messages = '.$msg.'<br>';
    }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In this case,If its a single and `TransportKey` and a single `ValidationKey` value (not an array/object is passed) at a time, this is the simplest**. Else if object contains objects or inside objects that we want to use or convert to variable, should use a `foreach` to loop through the object.

```
//Debuggig
//The string you provided is converted to a json object 
//In your case if it is a json object already pass directly it to $j
//below is just for debugging and understanding
//$json='{"CreateTransactionResponse":{"CreateTransactionResult":{"TransportKey":"aa900d54-7bfb-47e9-a5de-e423ec34a900","ValidationKey":"fbb28b32-f439-4801-a434-99c70aa388ca","Messages":{}}}}';
//$j=json_decode($json);

$transkey=$j->CreateTransactionResponse->CreateTransactionResult->TransportKey;
$vkey=$j->CreateTransactionResponse->CreateTransactionResult->ValidationKey;

echo $transkey."</br>";
echo $vkey."<br/>";
/*result as said: 
aa900d54-7bfb-47e9-a5de-e423ec34a900
fbb28b32-f439-4801-a434-99c70aa388ca
*/
```